# Trying to get all the links of the page, but only the ones in header tag are stored

Tags: php, dom

I have to get all links whose `nodeValue` is 'Download', but when I try to get all the links first, and then select the ones I need, only links that are in my `<header>` tag are picked up. 'Download' links are in the further down on the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the function:

```
<?php
function rkm_download_links_fix($current_url) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($current_url);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    print_r($urls); // here i get only links in <header>
    $url_copy = array();
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        print_r($url->nodeValue);
        if($url->nodeValue == 'download') {
            $attributes = $url->attributes;
            $url_copy[] = array('url' => $url->getAttribute('href'));
        }
    }
 } ?>
```

If you need more info, please do not hesitate to ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to supply a short HTML snippet of the HTML you are attempting to parse.

Comment: Are you sure your HTML is correct?

Comment: It is a wordpress post, so the url is dynamic, i call this function like so: `rkm_download_links_fix(get_the_permalink())`

Answer (score 0):

Why you need DOM?

Just simple php:

```
<?php

function getLinks($url)
{
    $document = file_get_contents($url);
    $links = explode('<a', $document);
    $resultLinks = array();

    if(count($links) <= 1)
        return 'no links';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($links); ++$i)
    {
        if(mb_strpos($links[$i], '>download</a>', 0, 'UTF-8') === false &&
            mb_strpos($links[$i], '>Download</a>', 0, 'UTF-8') === false)
            continue;

        $hrefStart = mb_strpos($links[$i], 'href', 0, 'UTF-8');
        if($hrefStart === false)
            continue;

        $hrefStart += 4;
        $hrefStart = mb_strpos($links[$i], '"', $hrefStart, 'UTF-8');
        if($hrefStart === false)
            $hrefStart = mb_strpos($links[$i], '\'', $hrefStart, 'UTF-8');
            if($hrefStart === false)
                continue;
        ++$hrefStart;

        $hrefEnd = mb_strpos($links[$i], '"', $hrefStart, 'UTF-8');
        if($hrefEnd === false)
            $hrefEnd = mb_strpos($links[$i], '\'', $hrefStart, 'UTF-8');
            if($hrefEnd === false)
                continue;

        $resultLinks[] = mb_substr($links[$i], $hrefStart, ($hrefEnd - $hrefStart), 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $resultLinks;
}

$links = getLinks('http://parse/ws/try2.html');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($links);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I need to get only the ones that have 'Download' as anchor text, not all of them...

Comment: I have edit my code. Now it will search only for urls with download or Download text between <a> and </a> tags

Comment: when i call it like so: `$links = rkm_download_links_fix(get_the_permalink());
print_r($links);` i get an empty array